# vs2012 is saying that my mapped drive is already in my workspace mapping

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have deleted my workspace,
and renamed the folder that the files where in

but everytime i start vs2012 -> connect to a new tfs server 
and then try to map a project to my local folder
vs2012 says that the folder d:/ is already mapped in the workspace

How do i delete this memory of the mapped path from vs2012?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out we copied the database underneath the old tfs server and used it for the new tfs server.

this kept all the workspaces on the new tfs server that where related to the old tfs server.
so we where trying to delete the workspaces from the old server, (which were actually deleted)

We then deleted the invalid workspaces on the new tfs server and ha presto it all works fine.